# Get array value by key in dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array that is dynamically generated using some another function. The multidimensional array consists of 3-d and 4-d elements. I have added example of array below.  Now user wants to set particular value of this array by passing only keys of the array (as user will not have access of this array directly). So I need method to access particular element of array by using the keys passed by user. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

User will pass something like 
e.g. $newdata["company"]["logo"]["data"] = "newlogourl";` and this value needs to be replaced in the original array.

```
Array
(
    [company] => Array
        (
            [logo] => Array
                (
                    [data] => https://www.sparksuite.com/images/logo.png
                    [style] => width:100%; max-width:300px
                )

            [name] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Company Name, Inc
                )

            [tagline] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Company Name, Inc
                )

        )

    [invoice] => Array
        (
            [no] => Array
                (
                    [data] => DY-13123
                    [label] => Invoice No: 
                    [style] => font-size:14px
                )

            [date] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 01-12-2018
                    [label] => Date: 
                )

            [total_due] => Array
                (
                    [data] => $56,890.23
                    [label] => Total Due: 
                    [display] => show
                )

        )

    [from] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Apple Test Inc 
                )

            [address1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 123 Seatle
                )

            [address2] => Array
                (
                    [data] => New jersy
                )

            [city] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Indore
                )

            [state] => Array
                (
                    [data] => M.P
                )

        )

    [to] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [data] => American Option
                )

            [address1] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 205, Apollo Tower, Near Palasia
                )

            [address2] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Opp. 56 Shops, M.G Road
                )

            [city] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Indore
                )

            [state] => Array
                (
                    [data] => M.P
                )

        )

    [payment] => Array
        (
            [method] => Array
                (
                    [data] => DY-13123
                    [label] => Payment methods: 

                )

            [note] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Thank you for Business with us!
                    [label] => 
                )

        )

    [footer] => Array
        (
            [note] => Array
                (
                    [data] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.
                    [label] => Terms and Conditions: 

                )

        )

    [itemcount] => Array
        (
            [count] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Sno.
                )

            [display] => show
        )

    [header] => Array
        (
            [style] => font-size:18px
            [display] => show
        )

)
```

Comment: what a key, for example, may be passed and what result you expact?

Comment: Please provide some more detail and perhaps some code

Comment: You could try using  `$arrayName['invoice']['no']['data'] = $value;`

Comment: User will pass key something like "company" "logo" "data" to set the array value of company logo data

Comment: e.g. $newdata["company"]["logo"]["data"] = "newlogourl"; and this value needs to be replaced in the original array.

Comment: User sends string '$newdata["company"]["logo"]["data"] = "newlogourl";' or array ?

Comment: If array, try  `array_replace_recursive` -  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php

Comment: We can use anyway (both string and array is ok), we just needs user to allow modify any value of existing dynamic array.

Comment: Ok, I will try using that. Thanks. Is this possible also to find the value before replacing it as I need to store that old value also. Please remember that user will be passing keys only so I can't directly find it in existing array. Thanks

Comment: @PriteshGupta have you solved your problem ?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I got solution for value replace. Is there any function to search and get value by passing in multidimensional array before replacing value?. Thanks